# Can I fail a test in MBUnit if an exception is thrown in FixtureTeardown?

Tags: mbunit

If a test goes into native code and throws an accessviolation on shutdown - MBUnit notices this but still passes the test (all the individual tests passed - but there was a crash on shutdown)

**So I see a failure:**

[failed] Fixture Inventory/Inventory
Tear Down
System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.

**But the test still shows as passed:**

3 run, 3 passed, 0 failed, 0 inconclusive, 0 skipped

**Is there a way I can make the test fail if an exception is caught in FixtureTearDown?**